# Filters for webflux spring boot app, which return ResponseEntity<?>

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

My spring boot application configured as reactive. But my REST API endpoints  configured for return ResponseEntity without Mono or Flux.

```
@GetMapping("/wiki/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        log.info("TEST CALLED????");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("HALLO");
    }
```

I want to implement filter which will check incoming headers for every endpoint. Old Servlet filters of course does not work, also not working new WebFilter for webflux and others.

My project located in github [wiki controller](https://github.com/armdev/microservices-security/blob/master/wiki/src/main/java/io/project/app/resources/WikiController.java)

I do not want use router based endpoints and I am prefer Netty under Spring boot. Which kind of filters I can use for both: reactive and servlet applications? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you not returning Mono<ResponseEntity>?

Comment: i should add a Mono to every response, imagine big application , people already wrote code like using ResponseEntity , so I want to change tomcat to webflux, but I do not want functional programming in the Rest Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "What kind of code would I write to work as a filter in both Reactive and non-Reactive Spring applications, the answer is you can't. You can write a simple class/bean that gets used from both the WebFilter or Filter, though.

Comment: I want to use Spring boot + netty, but I do no not want use functional programming in the REST controllers.

Comment: That's like saying you want to drive a Tesla but power it using petrol. You need to write non-blocking code when using Netty otherwise your server will only be able to support one transaction at a time per cpu core. Spring Webflux and Spring MVC are fundamentally different because the environments they work in are completely different.

Comment: yeah, whats why i like vertx, i think functional programming is not for controllers, webflux is fun, but it should be improved. thanks